# New $_SESSION variable not created after query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I'm trying to build a login process where, by using $_SESSION variables, the login credentials of the user are stored and used to show their relevant data from the database on screen (i.e. they will only see the school data that they work for).

```
   <?php    
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['Initials'], $_SESSION['Surname']))
{

 $host = "xxx";
 $username = "xxx";
 $password = "xxx";
 $database_name = "xxx";
 $table_name = "xxx";

 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) OR die("Can't  
 connect");
 mysql_select_db($database_name) OR die("Can't connect to 
 Database");

 $query = "SELECT Class FROM $table_name WHERE Initials = '". 
 $_SESSION['Initials']."' AND staff LIKE '%".$_SESSION['Surname']."'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $class = mysql_fetch_array($result);
 $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if($count === NULL)
 {
  echo "ERROR";
 }
  else
  {
  $_SESSION['Class'] = $result;
  echo "Class added to sessions";
  }
}
?>
```

My initial problem where the query couldn't recognize the session variables was easily solved by adding the correct brackets for the if-statement. My next problem that has arisen here is that even though the query should be successfull (I don't receive an error message saying 'ERROR' when the $count is either FALSE or NULL) it's not creating the result array into a new session, because when I print the session array on a new page it's still only carrying over the 'Initials' and 'Surname' sessions.

What do I need to change to my query, or post-query process in order for that array (because it's bound to throw up multiple results) to be made into a new session?

Many thanks for the answers to my initial problem!

Comment: You are missing the braces around your code block for the 'if' statement. That means only the very next statement is conditional - the rest is executed no matter what.

Comment: can't believe I missed such a small detail!!! Thanks a lot, the variables in the query are no longer not recognized, but unfortunately it's still not creating the new session (Class) at the end...(Does that have anything to do with the $count parameter?

Comment: What it seems to be related to is whether your database call succeeded. I suggest to not use the mysql_* functions much, since they're outdated and are going to be removed from php soon, by the way - use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: I've managed to figure out what the problem was (eventually) - Am not allowed to write down my answer yet since it's not been long enough but I will do once I'm able to so people can see - Thanks for the tip about the mysql!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer - it turned out that I wasn't treating one of the session variables as a proper array and thus wouldn't load properly. I've added my script below so that people with similar problems in the future can use it as a reference point:

```
<?php

 session_start();


 // Server Details //
 $host = "---";
 $username = "---";
 $password = "---";
 $database_name = "---";
 $table_name = "---";


 // Connect Command //
 mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) OR die("Can't  
 connect");
 mysql_select_db($database_name) OR die("Can't connect to 
 Database");


 // Query to call up the unique school name //
 $query_school = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT School FROM $table_name 
 WHERE Initials = '".$_SESSION['---']."'
 AND staff LIKE '%".$_SESSION['---']."'") or die( mysql_error());
 $result_school = mysql_result($query_school, 0);


 // Query to call up the unique centre no //
 $query_centreno = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT CentreNo FROM 
 $table_name WHERE Initials = '".$_SESSION['---']."'
 AND staff LIKE '%".$_SESSION['---']."'") or die( mysql_error());
 $result_centreno = mysql_result($query_centreno, 0);


 // The newly created sessions for school info //
 $_SESSION['---'] = $result_school;
 $_SESSION['---'] = $result_centreno;


 // Query to call up the array of classes //
 $query_class = mysql_query("SELECT Class FROM $table_name WHERE 
 Initials = '".$_SESSION['---']."'
 AND staff LIKE '%".$_SESSION['---']."'") or die( mysql_error());
 $query_class__array = array();
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_class))
 $query_class_array[] = $row;

 $_SESSION['---'] = $query_class_array;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['Initials'], $_SESSION['Surname'])) {
// code
}
```

u need { } brackets

> if(!isset($_SESSION['Initials'], $_SESSION['Surname']))
>
> $host = "xxxxx"; $username = "xxxxx"; $password = "xxxxx";

is

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['Initials'], $_SESSION['Surname'])) {

$host = "xxxxx";
}
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
```